# How to properly type NormalizedSchema as PayloadAction on redux-toolkit?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, normalizr, redux-toolkit

I decided to use `redux-toolkit` to lessen redux boilerplate. My problem is, I can't seem to find an example or proper way to type normalized payload?

I am using TS boilerplate on a React Native project.

This is my simplified use case.

**From types.d.ts**

```
import {PayloadAction} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import {NormalizedSchema} from 'normalizr';

declare type Pet = {
   id: string;
   name: string;
}

declare type NormalizedState<T> = {
  byIds: {
    [key: string]: T;
  };
  allIds: string[];
  // meta?: PaginatableMeta;
};

declare type NormalizedPayload<
  P,
  T extends string = string,
  M = never,
  E = never
> = PayloadAction<NormalizedSchema<P, string[]>, T, M, E>;
```

**Pet state slice**

```
const petsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'pets',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchPets() {},
    fetchPetsSuccess(
      state,
      {payload}: NormalizedPayload<{pets: {[key: string]: Pet}}>,
    ) {
      return state;
    },
  },
});
```

**From schema.ts**

```
import {schema} from 'normalizr';

export const pet = new schema.Entity('pets');
```

**Calling the `fetchPetsSuccess` reducer will throw a TS error**

```
import {normalize} from 'normalizr';
import {pet} from './schema';
import {Pet} from './types'
import slice from '.'

const petsList: Pet[] = [{
    id: 'myId',
    name: 'Foo'
}];

// TS error here
slice.reducer.fetchPetsSuccess(undefined, normalize(petsList, [pet]));
```

Comment: So... what is the TS error message?

Comment: Note that [the Redux Toolkit 1.3.0 alpha releases](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/releases) now include [a new API for generating reducers that help manage normalized state for you](https://deploy-preview-352--redux-starter-kit-docs.netlify.com/api/createEntityAdapter), including TS type definitions. Please try it out and give us feedback!

Comment: @markerikson Thanks, just what I needed. 

I think there is a small typo on the example, `bookUpdated` should be called like this?

`
bookUpdated({ id: 'a', changes: { id: 'a', title: 'First (altered)' } })
`

Comment: @markerikson My next question is, how can you normalize a Book entity with an array of Author entity?

Comment: Something like Normalizr, or hand-writing the normalization logic.  That's up to you to decide.